# Can I view the stdout and stderr of a process in 2 separate terminal windows?

Tags: bash

I often run multiple terminal windows, and would like to easily view the `stderr` of a process in one terminal window, while viewing the `stdout` in another.

Is this possible ? I'd like to have a generic command that I can launch any process, or pipe it to, that would let me do this easily.

e.g.

#### In one terminal window, I'd start my process

`$ ps aux | separate_stdout_and_stderr`

#### In 2 other terminal windows, I'd view the `stdout` and `stderr` of my process

- Terminal 1 has `stdout`
- Terminal 2 has `stderr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You need to know which tty you have by executing the `tty` command.

```
# Terminal 2
$ tty
/dev/pts/8
```

You can redirect the errors from terminal 1 to terminal 2 by redirecting stderr to that pts.

```
# Terminal 1
$ while true; do
    echo 1;
    echo 2 >&2;
    sleep 1;
done 2>/dev/pts/8
```

It will print `2` in terminal 2, and `1` in terminal 1.